# Usually a PL/SQL compilation error for output in not correct ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Create Table table7_prc (
                          Family    VARCHAR2(200),
                        
                          Name      VARCHAR2(200)
                       

                           ) ;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem (
    str IN VARCHAR2
) AS

BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO table_prc7 (Name ,Family)
       
        SELECT
        
            regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts 
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
          
          regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL ;
          
           SELECT
        
            regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level) AS  SARTS 
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
          
          regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL ; 
   

COMMIT ; 
END ;

BEGIN
    addnewmembe('faezeh;Ghanbarian,pari;izadi');
END;
```

I want to show in the result in the row a name and family in the coulmn of the table

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few errors (some typos, some syntax). If you're inserting into 2 columns, `select` statement must return 2 columns (yours is returning only one). Besides, you'll have to split each substring into additional two parts.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table7_prc
  2  (
  3     Family   VARCHAR2 (200),
  4     Name     VARCHAR2 (200)
  5  );

Table created.
```

Procedure: I removed a *standalone* `select` you put into the procedure. If you use it in PL/SQL, you must have an `INTO` clause. I don't know what you planned to do with it so I just removed it.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem (str IN VARCHAR2)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     INSERT INTO table7_prc (Name, Family)
  5        WITH
  6           temp
  7           AS
  8              (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
  9                                         '[^,]+',
 10                                         1,
 11                                         LEVEL) val
 12                     FROM DUAL
 13               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, ',') + 1)
 14        SELECT SUBSTR (val, 1, INSTR (val, ';') - 1),
 15               SUBSTR (val, INSTR (val, ';') + 1)
 16          FROM temp;
 17
 18     COMMIT;
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     addnewmem ('faezeh;Ghanbarian,pari;izadi');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table7_prc;

FAMILY               NAME
-------------------- --------------------
Ghanbarian           faezeh
izadi                pari

SQL>
```